# How to return a string from fetch-node function

Tags: javascript, json, themoviedb-api

I'm using the movie database API and try to play the trailer on the youtube for that I need the key value from the JSON response. I tried everything but the function either returns a promise or undefined. I tried to use a callback to return the result but that didn't work either.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
// function declaration 
async function trailer(id, callback) {
  var video = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + id + '/videos?api_key=' + apiKey +'&language=en-US';
  var key = await fetch(video)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => callback(json.results[0].key));
}

// function call returns a promise (expected key string ex."Zftx5a")
trailer(id, function(result){return result;})
```

Comment: Well, key is going to be undefined - that's for sure... What is key exactly?

Answer (score -1):

Since the `fetch` function makes an asynchronous call your `trailer` function returns `key` before the promise chain resolves. The easiest way of solving that issue is using an `async` function, so your code would be something like:

```
async function trailer(id) {
  var video = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + id + '/videos?api_key=' + apiKey +'&language=en-US';
  return await fetch(video)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => json.results[0].key);  
}
```

However, you must take into consideration that an `async` function will return a promise, so you will have to modify your code.

For further information check the following links:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#common-usage

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: If this will also return a promise what difference would it make? Well I tried to modify my code to get a string from the returned promise but nothing seemed to be working.